# Magento 2 REST Search Orders Starting at Order_ID

Tags: magento2

I'm writing a Magento2 integration and I'm trying to only get a list of orders by order_id since the last order_id that i have sync'd.

So, my orders search call would only get order_id's greater than the last order id that I've synced (i'll keep this in my app).

In this example, I only want order ID's greater than order_id = 20 and sorting by order_id ASC:

/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=order_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=20&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from[sortOrders][0][field]=order_id&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=asc

But i'm getting a 500 error thrown from the REST API when I run this.

Any ideas what is wrong with my call?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no `order_id` field in Magento 2 `sales_order` table. Instead of that you can use `entity_id` ( the primary key).

So your query url will be below and this will pull the orders greater than supplied order id.

```
https://yourhost.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=179&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=gt
```

Also post your Magento related queries in [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) for better visibility